# What are integration tests containing and how to set them up

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I’m currently learning about unit tests and integration testing and as I understood it, unit tests are used to test the logic of a specific class and integration tests are used to check the cooperation of multiple classes and libraries.

But is it only used to test multiple classes and if they work together as expected, or is it also valid to access databases in an integration test? If so, what if the connection can‘t be established because of a server sided error, wouldn’t the tests fail, although the code itself would work as expected? How do I know what‘s valid to use in this kind of tests?

Second thing I don‘t understand is how they are set up. Unit tests seem to me have a quite common form, like:

```
public class  classTest {

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
    }

    @Test
    public void testCase(){
    }
}
```

But how are integration tests written? Is it commonly done the same way, just including more classes and external factors or is there another way that is used for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [... ] is it also valid to access databases in an integration test? [...] How do I know what‘s valid to use in this kind of tests?

The distinction between unit-tests and integration tests is not whether or not more than one component is involved: Even in unit-testing you can get along without mocking all your dependencies if these dependencies don't keep you from reaching your unit-testing goals (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583329/5747415).

What distinguishes unit-testing and integration testing is the *goal* of the test.  As you wrote, in unit-testing your focus is on finding bugs in the logic of a function, method or class.  In integration testing the goal is then, obviously, to detect bugs that could not be found during unit-testing but can be found in the integrated (sub-)system.  Always keeping the test goals in mind helps to create better tests and to avoid unnecessary redundancy between integration tests and unit-tests.

One flavor of integration testing is interaction testing: Here, the goal is to find bugs in the interaction between two or more components.  (Additional components can be mocked, or not - again this depends on whether the additional components keep you from reaching your testing goals.)  Typical questions in the interactions of two components `A` and `B` could be, for example if `B` is a library: Is component `A` calling the right function of component `B`, is component `B` in a proper state to be accessed by `A` via that function (`B` might not be initialized yet), is `A` passing the arguments in the correct order, do the arguments contain the values in the expected form, does `B` give back the results in the expected way and in the expected format?

Another flavor of integration testing is subsystem testing, where you do not focus on the interactions between components, but look at the boundaries of the subsystem formed by the integrated components.  And, again, the goal is to find bugs that could not be found by the previous tests (i.e. unit-tests and interaction tests).  For example, are the components integrated in the correct versions, can the desired use-cases be exercised on the integrated subsystem etc.

While unit-tests form the bottom of the [test pyramid](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2015/06/27/the-test-pyramid), integration testing is a concept that applies on different levels of integration and can even focus on interfaces orthogonal to the software integration strategy (for example when doing interaction testing of a driver and its corresponding hardware device).

> Second thing I don‘t understand is how they are set up.  [...] how are integration tests written?

There is an extreme variation here.  For many integration tests you can just use the same testing framework that is used for unit-tests: There is nothing unit-test specific in these frameworks.  You will, certainly, in the test cases have to ensure that the setup actually combines the components of interest in their proper versions.  And, whether or not additional dependencies are just used or mocked needs to be decided (see above).

Another typical scenario is to perform integration tests in the fully integrated system, using a system-test-like setup.  This is often done out of convenience, just to avoid the trouble to create different special setups for the different integration tests: The fully integrated system just has them all combined.  Certainly, this has also disadvantages, because it is often impossible or at least impractical to perform all integration tests as desired this way.  And, when doing integration testing this way the boundaries between integration testing and system testing get fuzzy.  Keeping focused in such a case means you really have to have a good understanding of the different test goals.

There are also mixed forms, but there are too many to describe them here.  Just one example, there is a possibility to mock some shared libraries with the help of `LD_PRELOAD` ([What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! That definitely helps to understand it better in general. But still I struggle with the implementation and how to set it up. If I have for example client and server code and I want to test the registration code, would I test it by inserting a test user into the database? Or do I mock a database and only check if the client would pass the data through it‘s classes correctly to the database? I think I have a lack of imagination how this works

Comment: All this is possible, but which scenario is best depends on what bugs you are trying to find.  For example, mocking the database makes sense unless you also want to find possible bugs in the way your code talks to the database (e.g. bugs in the SQL commands).  If you want to discuss this, I have invited you to a chat room.

Comment: Okay, that definitely makes sense. Thank you, I indeed have questions about that topic and its usage, so I will definitely come back to that!

Answer (score 1):

It would be valid to access a database as part of an integration test, as integration tests are supposed to show whether a feature is working correctly.

If a feature were to not work because of a failed connection to a server side error, you would want the test to fail to inform you that this feature is not working. Integration tests are not there to inform you where the fault lies, just that a feature is not working.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876055/10461045 as this helps to clarify the widely accepted difference.

Comment: So would it also be possible to have an integration test that only checks if the connection to the database is established correctly, or wouldn’t that be something that gets tested?

Answer (score 1):

Using a database (or an external connection to a service you are using) in an integration test is not only valid, but should be done. However, do not rely on integration tests heavily. Unit test every logic element you have and set up integration tests for certain flows.

Integration tests can be written in the same way, except (as you mentioned) they include more methods etc. In fact, the code snippet you've shown above is a common start write-up of an integration test.

You can read up more on tests here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301479/are-database-integration-tests-bad